# Calculating Marginal and Conditional Probabilities from R Crosstable

Tags: probability, contingency-tables

I am having a difficult time understanding conditional and marginal probability when the variables are not discrete. I have three questions I am trying to answer:

What are the marginal probabilities for each value of VDEM\$Capacity and VDEM$Autonomy? **Would it simply be the bottom number of the Column Total and Row Total respectively?**

What are the conditional probabilities for each value of VDEM$Autonomy? **Would this be the bottom number (N/Table Total) of each cell?**

What is the the conditional expectation of VDEM\$Autonomy when VDEM$Capacity = 0 (“No”)?

````
   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
| Chi-square contribution |
|           N / Row Total |
|           N / Col Total |
|         N / Table Total |
|-------------------------|

 
Total Observations in Table:  23710 

 
              | VDEM$Capacity 
VDEM$Autonomy |         No | Not really |  Ambiguous |     Almost |        Yes |  Row Total | 
--------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
           No |       6224 |       2642 |       1201 |       1478 |        359 |      11904 | 
              |   2185.109 |    177.379 |     91.126 |    681.285 |   1283.086 |            | 
              |      0.523 |      0.222 |      0.101 |      0.124 |      0.030 |      0.502 | 
              |      0.900 |      0.650 |      0.382 |      0.258 |      0.093 |            | 
              |      0.263 |      0.111 |      0.051 |      0.062 |      0.015 |            | 
--------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
     Somewhat |        567 |        884 |        645 |        873 |         65 |       3034 | 
              |    113.958 |    254.722 |    145.590 |     26.484 |    371.610 |            | 
              |      0.187 |      0.291 |      0.213 |      0.288 |      0.021 |      0.128 | 
              |      0.082 |      0.218 |      0.205 |      0.152 |      0.017 |            | 
              |      0.024 |      0.037 |      0.027 |      0.037 |      0.003 |            | 
--------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
    Ambiguous |         98 |        410 |        923 |       1186 |        188 |       2805 | 
              |    633.466 |     10.423 |    813.956 |    380.132 |    157.365 |            | 
              |      0.035 |      0.146 |      0.329 |      0.423 |      0.067 |      0.118 | 
              |      0.014 |      0.101 |      0.293 |      0.207 |      0.049 |            | 
              |      0.004 |      0.017 |      0.039 |      0.050 |      0.008 |            | 
--------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
       Almost |         23 |        127 |        373 |       1953 |       1477 |       3953 | 
              |   1106.848 |    447.366 |     43.930 |   1040.322 |   1084.376 |            | 
              |      0.006 |      0.032 |      0.094 |      0.494 |      0.374 |      0.167 | 
              |      0.003 |      0.031 |      0.118 |      0.341 |      0.383 |            | 
              |      0.001 |      0.005 |      0.016 |      0.082 |      0.062 |            | 
--------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
          Yes |          0 |          1 |          6 |        243 |       1764 |       2014 | 
              |    587.126 |    343.212 |    255.535 |    122.234 |   6306.871 |            | 
              |      0.000 |      0.000 |      0.003 |      0.121 |      0.876 |      0.085 | 
              |      0.000 |      0.000 |      0.002 |      0.042 |      0.458 |            | 
              |      0.000 |      0.000 |      0.000 |      0.010 |      0.074 |            | 
--------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
 Column Total |       6912 |       4064 |       3148 |       5733 |       3853 |      23710 | 
              |      0.292 |      0.171 |      0.133 |      0.242 |      0.163 |            | 
--------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
```
````

Comment: 1. Yes.  2. No -  it is the `N / Col Total` numbers since the conditionality is on being in that column of a particular `VDEM$Capacity`value. 3. You will have to calculate this yourself based on the answer to (2)  and whatever numerical values you are using to translate the words

Comment: In what sense are these variables "not discrete"??